# Every isosceles trapezoid has an inscribed circle

Tags: geometry

I think it's not true but I'm not sure about it . Can we use Pitot theorem here ? For example a trapezoid with long bases and short legs can't have an inscribed circle . Please explain about the conditions for an isosceles trapezoid to have an inscribed circle .

Comment: at the first step i would make an image

Comment: Not every isosceles trapezium has an inscribed circle, but they all have a circumscribed circle.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What's the conditions for it to have an inscribed circle ?

Comment: $\overline{AB} + \overline{CD} = \overline{BC} + \overline{AD}$.

Comment: @HwChu Post as an answer?

Comment: @HwChu So Pitot theorem is sufficient in this case ?

Comment: @HwChu Indeed that's the condition for a general convex quadrilateral to have an inscribed circle.

Comment: Yes I believe it is sufficient.

Comment: @HwChu Can you prove it ?

Comment: Oh wait wiki actually said the converse holds whenever the quadrilateral is convex :)

Comment: Okay , Thanks a lot .

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So $\overline{AB} + \overline{CD} = \overline{BC} + \overline{AD}$ is sufficient and necessary condition for having an inscribed circle ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this figure.
[image]

I claim that if one of those trapezoids has an inscribed circle, the other does not.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

If a quadrilateral has an inscribed circle it has to satisfy $\overline{AB} + \overline{CD} = \overline{BC} + \overline{AD}$. This is Pitot's theorem. The converse is also true.

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral satisfying $\overline{AB} + \overline{CD} = \overline{BC} + \overline{AD}$. If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram then it is a rhombus, which has an inscribed circle. Now suppose that $\overline{BC}$ is not parallel to $\overline{AD}$. Let $P$ be the intersection of the line $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$. Then the triangle $\triangle PCD$ has a inscribed circle.

Find $A'$ on the segment $\overline{PC}$ and $B'$ on the segment $\overline{PD}$ so that $\overline{A'B'}$ is parallel to $\overline{AB}$. If you vary $A'$ and $B'$ under this condition, there is a unique pair of $\{A'_0, B'_0\}$ satisfying $\overline{A'_0B'_0} + \overline{CD} = \overline{A'_0D} + \overline{B'_0C}$, and there is a unique pair of $\{A'_1, B'_1\}$ satisfying $\overline{A'_1B'_1}$ is tangent to the inscribed circle. $\{A'_0, B'_0\}$ must coincide $\{A'_1, B'_1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If the parallel sides of the trapezium have lengths $a$ and $b$ then by consideration of the tangents to the inscribed circle, the non-parallel slant edges would have to have their lengths both equal to $$\frac{a+b}{2}$$

Comment: How we can prove that it's the sufficient condition ?

Comment: @S.H.W you should rephrase your question to ask for mecessary and sufficient conditions. I have provided necessary conditions, which are easy enough to prove using elementary geometry.

Comment: Okay , can we use Pitot theorem in this case ?

Comment: Use it to do what, exactly?

Comment: To conclude that the $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is sufficient and necessary condition .

Comment: Necessary, yes.

Comment: Can you explain why it's not sufficient condition ? In the wiki's article has wrote that converse of theorem is also true .

Comment: You would have to start with slant edges $=\frac{a+b}{2}$ and show that you can inscribe a circle. So Pitot's theorem cannot be assumed in this case. However you would use the basic circle geometry (equal tangents) which Pitot is based on.